# Strange requests to my server

Tags: web-application, web-scanners

I recently checked my logs and found some strange requests to my server. eg

```
GET /path/Microsoft.XMLHTTP HTTP/1.0
GET /path2/Scripting.FileSystemObject HTTP/1.0
```

A further check seems to point to some robot doing web site archival. Would a web archival bot execute such requests in the form of commands to archive our site?

For example, if it is from [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/archive.org_bot) or some library which does archival, would these archival bots actually perform such requests ? I though they would just do spidering or grab the whole website, and not invoke such commands.

Update:

Upon further investigation, I found that the archival bot probably went deeper into analysing a javascript at that page and grabbing those statements that contain `Scripting.FileSystem`, eg

```
var FSO = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
```

Probably the reason is the bot needs to get everything that it could find, so even ActiveXobjects. Is it logical to think this way?

Comment: Why do you think this is a legitimate spider? Doesn't sound like it judging by what it is doing.

Comment: Still using ActiveX? I hope you aren't expecting any users using other browsers than Internet Explorer before Edge.

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong, I do not know how web archival bots work actually. I suppose while trying to get contents off the site, and if those sites make use of javascript in order to display content, then the bot will try to also "simulate" some sort of client side action to get contents ? A normal spider would not be able to simulate javascript client side actions without using some special method?

Comment: I don't believe Javascript is executed by archival bots. It would be very expensive and unlikely to be useful. More likely they actively avoid Javascript to reduce the risk of polluting the archive with potential malware.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be a bot looking for common vulnerabilities in websites. Such bots are very commonly run by black-hat hackers to identify potential hacking targets. All websites get scanned by such bots regularly. It is unlikely to be an attack specifically targeted at you.

The only useful defense is to make sure that you don't have any vulnerable web applications on your site. If you use any standard software on your server (on the whole stack from operating system to individual scripts), make sure they are always up to date.

Comment: I wouldn't say that's the "only" defense. Such script kiddy attacks will usually run through a set of attempts to break your server, and of they don't succeed will move on to their next victim. WHILE THIS IS NOT A SUBSTITUTE FOR GOOD PATCH MANAGEMENT, running something like Fail2ban with a comprehensive set of attack signatures against your webserver logs provides an additional layer of assurance.

Comment: thanks. what if the bot is from an legit source that does archival? Those requests seems very suspicious because it is trying to probe using commands and not doing the normal spidering

Comment: @Pang Ser Lark: You can conclude that the archival server you are talking of was hacked. I advise you to report it with the extract from your logs to `abuse@archival_server_domain`. This may help them.

Comment: hi i have updated my findings.

Comment: I've seen lots requests like this to my public facing applications. However, what shocks me is that I also receive similar requests to web apps running on my local development machine. Does it mean my machine or my home network is compromised? Any advice on how to stop it. Thanks.

Comment: @ToànNguyễn Please don't use comments on questions to ask followup questions that go beyond the scope of the original question.

Answer (score 3):

It is very common to see the vulnerability scanner requests in the server logs.

Default pages of all major web, database administration tools, Linux and Windows, are checked sooner or later, regardless of what you are actually using.

The bots look for the default (unchanged) passwords. Bots also try to find other vulnerabilities and check maybe you use outdated software with known security problems.

You can even purchase such such scanner services from some providers. The company will scan your site periodically, simply reporting all discovered issues to you.

Comment: thanks. what if the bot is from an legit source that does archival? Those requests seems very suspicious because it is trying to probe using commands and not doing the normal spidering

Comment: No, going to the default admin page and probing a default password there is unlikely to be "from an legit source".

Comment: hi i have updated my findings.